# Asynchronous File Upload Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, file-upload, nio

Is it recommended to use asynchronous or NIO servlet for file upload?  If so, a good sample code to start will do a great help for me.

I'd like to know which version of Tomcat supports Async / NIO servlet too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### No...

...use the standard blocking IO stuff.

NIO does not automagically translate to 'faster' than old school blocking IO.  In fact, many [people have reported degraded performance with asynchronous NIO](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1377014/EmberIO-Dispelling-NIO-Myths) implementations for years, on top of the code being considerably more complex to code, understand, maintain and debug.

If that doesn't scare you off, remember two important engineering concepts:

- [Keep It Simple, Stupid!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)
- Avoid [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: is it still the same, even after all these years? Doesn't bytebuffer offer something new?

Comment: @Guru nope.  And K.I.S.S + avoiding premature optimization concepts still apply